# Get value from last function call

Tags: haskell, recursion

I want to write this method in Haskell:

```
private static int maxSubSumme(int array[])
{
    int maximum  = 0;
    int maxright = 0;

    for(int i=array.length-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        maxright = Math.max(maxright + array[i], 0);
        maximum = Math.max(maximum, maxright);
    }

    return maximum; 
}
```

I tried with this code:

```
maxSubSumme :: [Int] -> Int
maxSubSumme [x] = x
maxSubSumme (x:l) | maxright < maximum = maximum 
                  | maxright > maximum = maxright
                  where 
                      maxright = maxi (x + (maxSubSumme l)) 0
                      maximum  = maxi maximum maxright -- Here is my problem

maxi :: Int -> Int -> Int
maxi x y | x > y     = x
         | otherwise = y
```

I have to get the old maximum but I have no idea how I can do this. Is it possible to get the maximum from the last function call?

Comment: Could you expand the code a little bit? I don't see what oldRest is supposed to be in this code or how the rest function is used.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense.  You are saying `rest` is the max of some value and itself.  So you have a recursive definition of a value that is not possible to solve without assuming some initial value for `rest`.

Comment: @Cilenco If you've found your problem, it's helpful to others to leave the post as it was, so if someone has the same problem they can see the solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd write this, your code is constantly updating on variable on each loop, to me that looks like a fold,

```
myMax :: Ord a => [a] -> a
myMax (x:xs) = foldl' bigger x xs
  where bigger a x = max a x
```

Or just

```
 myMax :: Ord a => [a] -> a
 myMax = foldl1 max
```

`foldl` basically takes a list `x:y:z...`, an initial element `a`, and a function `f` and returns

```
(((a `f` x) `f` y) `f` z) ...
```

If you need explicit recursion,

```
 myMax (x:xs) = go x xs
   where go curr (x:xs) = go (max curr x) xs
         go curr  _     = curr
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions don't have explicit state, if you want to carry around the previous value you have to do it explicitly:

```
myMax [] = error "Empty list"
myMax [x] = x
myMax (x:xs) = go x xs
    where
        go y [] = y
        go y (y1:ys) = if y > y1
            then go y ys
            else go y1 ys
```